# UNC Path in SQL doesn't work anymore

Tags: ms-access, vba

I was successfully pulling data from a shared Access database on the network without having to link to it using the following command

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_WITH_DATA SELECT * FROM \\server.name.COM\folder\dir_name\MyDatabase.accdb.TABLE_WITH_DATA;
```

but the server name changed to the following format and now it doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_WITH_DATA SELECT * FROM \\server.name.com\folder\new_dir_name$\MyDatabase.accdb.TABLE_WITH_DATA;
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Given you are granted rights to the new folder, it should work. If not, it could be the $ sign.

Comment: I know $ is often **pre-fixed** on a network share, but I've never seen it used as a suffix? Are you sure that's the correct directory/folder name?

Comment: @Minty  Actually, it's more like this... \new_dir_name$\HH\previouspath\MyDatabase. Where HH was the root the company shared.